# C++ programs not compiling

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple hello world program:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
   
int main(){
   cout<<"Hello";
}
```

But it is reporting an error:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\istream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\sstream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\complex:45,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ccomplex:39,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:54,
                 from AAY.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:214:11: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
  214 |       _T1 7
      |           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h: In constructor 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair()':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:245:9: error: class 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>' does not have any field named 'first'  
  245 |       : first(), second() { }
```

and so on.

Basically, it says that `std::pair` does not have a member named `first` although I haven't used any. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Probably header file corrupted. Uninstall and reinstall gcc.

Comment: You can also use https://www.onlinegdb.com/ for small programs.

Comment: Also read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: The first two lines are (in)famous antipatterns; please don‘t use them.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: It looks like someone or something has replaced a "first" in your header with a "7". Reinstall and make a fresh start - even if you successfully fix that prticular problem, there's no telling what else might be broken.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use

`#include<bits/stdc++.h>`

This is not a C++ compliant header file.

Please use `#include <iostream>` instead and it should be sufficient.

Of course you may have also a problem with your compiler installation.